# unable to boot into my Linux

Tags: linux, boot

I am using ubuntu 11.04 (or rather was using it). I was following [this](http://blog.bodhizazen.net/linux/lxc-linux-containers/) tutorial. After I finished it, I shut down the computer and haven't been able to log back in.

Basically what is happening is that i am getting the grub screen.

so i have two questions:

1. What has caused this ?
2. What are my options here ? Have I lost my filesystem somehow ? can I get get back my data ?

please help me.

Comment: http://sourceforge.net/p/boot-repair/home/Home/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what caused it but you can try booting with the LiveCD and then [Install Grub back to your hard drive](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RecoveringUbuntuAfterInstallingWindows) Or you can download a bootable version of [Super Grub Disk](http://www.supergrubdisk.org/) and put that onto a CD or USB and boot from it and boot into your Ubuntu installation.

Comment: ok can you say if 

**1.** Making changes to `/etc/fstab` or
**2.** `mount /cgroup` which will try to mount cgroups automatically or
**3** making changes to `etc/network/interfaces` or
**4** making changes to `/etc/resolv.conf` 
cause my file system to crash ?